# When is google going to stop supporting c2dm push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I have been using android c2dm push notifications for my app, but since Google is going to stop c2dm I need to know how fast I should move all my users to android GCM so as to avoid any problems faced by my app users.

Comment: when its going to stop working?  good question but not the right place. Stack-overflow  is programmatic question and answer related site. post the question in metastackoverflow:)

Comment: @Raghav This question should absolutely NOT be posted on Meta. It does in no way belong there.

Answer (score 3):

C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

GCM is the right option for you.

Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices. This could be a lightweight message telling the Android application that there is new data to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly). The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on the target device

This document describes how to write an Android application and the server-side logic, using the helper libraries (client and server) provided by GCM.

Check these links,

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/19226-android-push-notification-gcm-framework-tutorial.html

http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/

for client side app you can find the code here

https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the notice in the [official page of c2dm](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/),

> Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012.
>   This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota
>   requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using
>   C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to
>   migrate to the new version of C2DM, called Google Cloud Messaging for
>   Android (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more
>   information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

This means, you can continue using c2dm, it will work as before. But there won't be any support for it going forward. Any new features would be added to GCM.

By the way migration to GCM is pretty simple, and they have helper libraries for GCM. Move to it asap for reliable and quota-less delivery.

Comment: C2DM users cannot receive GCM Push Notifications. That's why i want to know when C2DM service is going to end ?

Comment: c2dm and GCM are using 2 independent frameworks, and is not to be mixed. Either you implement c2dm or GCM. Don't think about supporting both. There is no "end" to the c2dm service, its going to keep working.

Comment: I am not mixing both. I have already implemented c2dm way before GCM came but now i am about to release new version with GCM so i think that there will be few users who will not upgrade the app and will remain with c2dm. That's why i wanted to know when c2dm is going to stop working so that i can force my uers to upgrade the app.

Answer (score 0):

Google has announced end of life for C2DM notifications.  The end of life date is July 30, 2015.

Found on the [C2DM home page](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/):

> Important: C2DM was officially deprecated on June 26, 2012, and will
>   be shut down completely as of July 30, 2015. Existing C2DM developers
>   are encouraged to migrate to [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) (GCM).
>   See the [C2DM-to-GCM Migration document](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html) for more information.
>   Developers must use GCM for new development.